# Is EOFILE needed when decoding images off base64?

Tags: php, base64

I see how WAMP does this, and I want to implement this technique to my website to get the image encryption from the database, basically what I'm doing so far; but whenever I echo out the base64 decode with the 'EOFILE' in the variable, the image results in errors.

BUT, whenever I only have the base64 decode echo without the 'EOFILE's added in the variable, the image shows.

My question is, is there a way to add a variable in the <<< EOFILE . $x . EOFILE;

OR it's completely OK to not include the 'EOFILE's in the PHP code.

Here are some references:

WAMP, using the 'EOFILE' when assigning the encryption to the variable:

```
$pngPlugin = <<< EOFILE
//base64 encryption of the image
EOFILE;
```

What I'm trying, with no EOFILE:

```
//note that the file when uploaded will get base64_encode() to the DB
$test = file_get_contents('./image.png');
$test2 = base64_encode($test);
//then implemented this way on the page via the DB
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo base64_decode($test2);
```

Adding variables to the <<< EOFILE doesn't really work for some reason, but is it really needed? I never used EOFILE in PHP before, and google didn't really do anything good for me, but how important is it? Do I need to worry about it if I don't have it included in my code?

Also, what is the '<<<' used for in PHP?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EOFILE` is an arbitrary identifier in the [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax which is used to define string literals.

You can choose any identifier, e.g.:

```
$i = <<< EOM
The message goes here.
EOM;
```

However, if you already have a variable containing base64 encoded data (such as from a database) you can simply do this:

```
echo base64_decode($str);
```

Comment: So it's not needed to have a EOM or EOFILE when outputting a base64 encryption? Or one of the examples in the link you provided has functions and variables included in the string, maybe tinkering with that may give out something in return? (no dots to separate the variables in the string?)

Comment: Heredoc syntax (what you're referring to as EOFILE) is simply a way of embedding some text in PHP source code, just like `"quoted strings"`. If you want to store the data in a separate file, that's fine, and you don't need to use a heredoc.